# Drop rows from Pandas DataFrame based on value after decimal

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rows, drop

I have big DF with values and names. After interpolating values with increment 0.1 I want to remove the rows with numbers such as 1111.123, and keep only rows with 1111.0, 1111.1, 1111.2 (or 1111.100...)

| Value | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1111.1 | Mark |
| 1111.2 | Mark |
| 1111.234 | Mark |
| 1111.3 | Mark |
| 1111.346 | Mark |
| 1111.4 | Mark |

I've tried `Series.str.split()` by string but it is too slow for CSV bigger than 1 GB. I've tried regex with

```
m = df['Value'].str.filter(regex='(\d*)\.(\d{3})')
```

But it returns empty Series.

Another option I've tried is `math.modf`, but it returns

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty,
> a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Here is the code itself:

```
import pandas as pd
from math import modf

df = pd.read_csv("file.csv")

split = ((df['Value'].apply(lambda x: modf(x)[0])) * 10).apply(lambda x: modf(x)[0])
target_value = 0 < split < 1
df1 = df.loc[split == target_value]
*some code to remove rows*
```

The final result I expect is:

| Value | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1111.1 | Mark |
| 1111.2 | Mark |
| 1111.3 | Mark |
| 1111.4 | Mark |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want to convert your floats to string, use this simple math trick to check whether there are decimals after the first one:

```
df[(df['Value']*10%1).eq(0)]
```

Alternatively, you can simple check if the second to last character is a `.`:

```
df[df['Value'].astype(str).str[-2].eq('.')]
```

output:

```
    Value  Name
0  1111.1  Mark
1  1111.2  Mark
3  1111.3  Mark
5  1111.4  Mark
```

Answer (score 0):

First is necessary read values like strings and then test pattern digits, '.' and one last digit:

```
df = pd.read_csv("file.csv", dtype={'Value':str})
df = df[df['Value'].str.match('\d+\.\d{1}$')]
```

Another idea without converting to strings, but possible float accuracy problems like `1111.100000000094894`:

```
s = df['Value'] * 10
df = df[s.eq(s.astype(int))]
print (df)
    Value  Name
0  1111.1  Mark
1  1111.2  Mark
3  1111.3  Mark
5  1111.4  Mark
```

Comment: This gives an error as my values are float. Converting the values to strings is a tough task as I have more than 2 mln rows

Comment: @OrkhanMammadov - is necessary converting to strings, if floats then accuracy problems, not sure if working correctly.

Comment: @OrkhanMammadov you can extract the decimal part after multiplication by 10 (see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69374896/16343464)), however I don't know if this is faster than string conversion

Answer (score 0):

Exclude any row which doesnt have 1 as a single digit between the dot and the end or does not have 0 between the dot and and end.

```
df[(df['Value'].astype(str).str.contains('(?<=\.)[^0]$|(?<=\.)[1]$'))]



   Value  Name
0  1111.1  Mark
1  1111.2  Mark
3  1111.3  Mark
5  1111.4  Mark
```

Based on your comment lets try

```
        Value   Name
0  1111.100000   Mark
1  1111.200000   Mark
2  1111.230000   Mark
3  1111.300000   Mark
4  1111.346000   Mark
5  1111.400000   Mark
6  1111.100099  Added
```

Output

```
    Value  Name
0  1111.1  Mark
1  1111.2  Mark
3  1111.3  Mark
5  1111.4  Mark
```

Comment: If I check the values on python, the numbers looks like this 1111.100000000094894. Not always it has 1 digit after dot

Comment: See an added example. Your scenario is covered and ouput as expected

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 df["value"] = df["value"].apply(lambda x: x - x % 0.1)
```